# Make python class "vars-able"

Tags: python

I have a python class:

```py
class myclass:
    a_a = "a---a"
    b_b = "b---b"
```

I would like to be able to use `vars(myclass)` to get a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"a_a" : "a---a", "b_b" : "b---b"}
```

It shuold do so dynamically, so that if I add something in `myclass` I dont have to update the information twice.

Comment: You can write your own dictionary (or mapping) class which implements this behavior.

Comment: `vars` just returns an object's `__dict__` attribute, and classes need their `__dict__` to not behave like this - particularly, there's other important stuff that needs to go in a class's attribute dict, plus there are memory-safety reasons that looking up `__dict__` on a class gives you a mappingproxy instead of an actual dict.

Comment: Why do you want to use a class for this? It doesn't sound like a class is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @user2357112 There are many python-techniques not useful for good design but still useful for things like advanced introspection, adapting legacy code for new usages, etc. Example: all of the `inspect`-module.

Comment: @julaine: Changing how `vars` works on a class doesn't help with any of that, though. It just breaks everything that relies on the normal behavior, without adding anything that wouldn't have been better handled a different way.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree changing what `vars` does on a class is not a good idea. I interpreted the question to mean "Can I do an operation like this which is kind of like `vars`" which I believe is a good question.

Answer (score 3):

The `__dict__`-attribute gives you this:

```
myclass.__dict__
>>> {'__module__': '__main__', 'a_a': 'a---a', 'b_b': 'b---b', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'myclass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'myclass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

This includes stuff you probably don't want, such as dunder-attributes, class-methods and get-set-descriptors.
To filter them, use this:

```
{k: v for k, v in myclass.__dict__.items()             
   if not k.startswith('__')
   and not callable(v)
   and not callable(getattr(v, "__get__", None))}
>>> {'a_a': 'a---a', 'b_b': 'b---b'}
```

(This result is now an actual `dict` and not a `mappingproxy` like the `__dict__`-method above because the dictionary comprehension creates a new dictionary)

Edit: you can replace `a.__dict__()` with `vars(a)` as these are equivalent as vars just returns the `__dict__` [(official docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars). It is considered good practice to not use dunder-methods directly. Using vars gives you a `dict` directly and not a `mappingproxy`. However I find that direct `__dict__`-access pops up a lot in real code.

Comment: can I add this somehow to the class such that any of the usual built in python suspects return this? fine if it is not `vars`

Comment: @safex I do not know of a way to do that. Whats wrong with just putting it in a normal function?

Comment: import to understand, *`myclass.__dict__` is just* `vars(myclass)`